# Android App Crashes, does not get past splashscreen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

We have an issue where our application is freezing, then after restarting the application, it does not get past the splash screen.

Below is the part of the logcat file that is displaying the error.

We can uninstall, and re-install and it will work again.

04-25 12:47:51.916  1247  4085 I ActivityManager: Start proc 8953:com.afs.dsd_mobile/u0a148 for activity com.afs.dsd_mobile/md50e18fe10ed511c2a0e92173f323ceb6a.MainActivity
04-25 12:47:52.298  1247  3521 D WifiService: New client listening to asynchronous messages
04-25 12:47:52.462  1247  4019 E WifiService: Param is :UserType
04-25 12:47:52.469  1247  3928 E WifiService: Param is :UserType
04-25 12:47:52.675  1247  3980 I ActivityManager: Start proc 8975:com.symbol.mxmf.csp.cellularmgr/u0a60 for service com.symbol.mxmf.csp.cellularmgr/.MxCellularMgrCSPService
04-25 12:47:52.867  1247  4019 I ActivityManager: Start proc 8988:com.symbol.osx.proxyframework.settingshelper/1000 for service com.symbol.osx.proxyframework.settingshelper/.SettingsServiceHelper
04-25 12:47:52.957  1247  4085 I ActivityManager: Process com.afs.dsd_mobile (pid 8953) has died
04-25 12:47:52.958  1247  4085 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 8953
04-25 12:47:52.972  1247  4085 I ActivityManager: Start proc 9000:com.afs.dsd_mobile/u0a148 for activity com.afs.dsd_mobile/md50e18fe10ed511c2a0e92173f323ceb6a.MainActivity
04-25 12:47:53.098  1247  4004 I ActivityManager: Start proc 9014:com.symbol.mxmf.csp.usbmgr/u0a89 for service com.symbol.mxmf.csp.usbmgr/.MxUsbMgrCSPService
04-25 12:47:54.034  1247  4028 I ActivityManager: Process com.afs.dsd_mobile (pid 9000) has died
04-25 12:47:54.034  1247  4028 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 9000
04-25 12:47:54.034  1247  4028 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{72b0be8 u0 com.afs.dsd_mobile/md50e18fe10ed511c2a0e92173f323ceb6a.MainActivity t14}: app died, no saved state
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
**04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@92eb2c9 does not exist**
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8795)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8786)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2726)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:197)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5606)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3409)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
04-25 12:47:54.041  1247  1296 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
04-25 12:47:54.051  1247  4028 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@6187b9f attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@513375

Comment: Does any combo of clearing the application Data &| Cache in settings allow the app to start again without the ViewRootImpl error? And is this limited to a particular device API level?

Comment: None of this log is the source of the crash. Look for an error marked as 'Fatal'

Comment: Have you used the debugger and stepped through the code to se which line of code that is the cause?

Comment: Can be everything without code impossible to evaluate, error in splash screen, some buggy line in mainactivity.. in main and splash activity install custom ex handler to help catch the error: AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironmentUnhandledExceptionRaiser;     then       private void AndroidEnvironmentUnhandledExceptionRaiser(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
     {
   string str = e.Exception.ToString();//whatever
  }

Comment: set the handler in the OnCreate()..